# Loop retrieve data from csv, append to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv

I have created a Python 2.7 script that does the following:

> 1. Gets a list of filenames from a folder, and writes them to a csv file, one for each row.

And

> 2. Enters data into a search box on the web.
> 3. Writes the result from the search box into another csv file.

So what I would like now, is for the csv data in (1 ) to act as the input for (2 ).

i.e. for each filename in the csv file, it conducts a search for that cell.

Additionally, instead of just writing the results into a second csv file in (3 ), I would like to append the result into the first csv file – OR generate a new one with both columns.

I can provide the code, but since it's 50 lines already, I've just tried to keep this question descriptive.

**Update: Proposed retrieval and append:**

```
with open("file.csv","a+") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\n")
    result = []
    for line in r:
        searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name("searchbox")
        searchbox.send_keys(line)

        sleep(8)

        search_reply = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search_reply")

        result = re.findall("((?<=\()[0-9]*)", search_reply.text)
    wr.writerow(result)
```

Comment: where did you have the problem? 1,2 or 3?

Comment: The problem is mainly in 2. – I don't know how to create a loop that reads data from a csv file. It should take each row from 1. and pass it on as a request for 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open for reading and appending, store the output then write at the end:

```
import csv
with open("first.csv","a+") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    result = []
    for line in r:
        # process lines/step 2
        # append to result
    wr.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Append the re output to the result list then write outside the loop. Moving the write outside the loop is essential

Comment: Thank you. How can I add the search result to the second column? If I do writerow, it will begin a new row.

Comment: For that you will have to write to a temp file and then updater the original with the temp file content